# Which versions of Windows does a MacBook Pro from 2008 support with Boot Camp?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp

Can my Mac use Windows? And if so, which Windows do I get?

Version: OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.16)
MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2008) 
8GB Memory

Comment: The latest version of Windows supported on your MacBook Pro is Windows 7 and you'd need an authentic Microsoft Windows full install disc or ISO file of Windows 7 64-bit or Windows 7 32-bit. Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) or later is required. Have a look at: [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/HT205016)

Comment: The oldest Mac that I have running Windows 10 is a 2007 iMac. This does not guarantee you can run Windows 10 on your Mac. You would have to attempt an install to find out. Currently, Microsoft does not charge for trying Windows 10. If you decide to keep using Windows 10, then you will need to buy a license. Does your optical drive work?

Comment: Also if you install Windows 7 you will get no more updates starting in january of 2020, essentially obsoleting WIndows 7.